# Use foreach instead of while with mysqli_fetch_object

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there any method to use `foreach` instead of `while` with `mysqli_fetch_object($query)`?

For example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
    echo $row->title;
}
```

How to use it with Foreach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IF you have PHP 5.4 you could do this:

```
// Using iterators (support was added with PHP 5.4)
foreach ( $c->query('SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user') as $row ) {
    printf("'%s'@'%s'\n", $row['user'], $row['host']);
}
```

LIke this you use the iterator to loop through every result set and then you can use it as `$row`
a

Comment: Thanks. I'm creating an application and I want to make it working with lower php versions, too.

Comment: @MMPP Why? You should keep your versions up-to-date

Comment: I have all versions up-to-date. I want to allow users to download and use it. That's why I want to make it working with some php versions. However, best answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hm. I think there's no other way to actually use a foreach to loop through a result set

Comment: No problem. I will keep while.